# Libgdx - How can i store pixmap line path for collision check?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to check for collision with the current touch point and a previously drawn pixmap line, meaning I must not touch the previously touched line or I must not overlap the coordinates of the line with my current touched coordinates.

I am drawing pixmap on drag like this.

```
int lastX,lastY;
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    UP = false;
    lastX = screenX;
    lastY = screenY;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    UP=false;
    pixmap.setColor(Color.RED);
    pixmap.drawLine(lastX, lastY, screenX, screenY);
    lastX = screenX;
    lastY = screenY;
    linetexture.draw(pixmap, 0, 0);
    return true;
}
```

So, what I want is: I must not touch the drawn line coordinates again, and to do that I need to store the pixmap line coordinates, but if I try it on the drag method and if I drag fast it doesn't store all the points on the drag path.

How can I store the path of the line efficiently to check that my current touch point (Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.GetY()) is not overlapping the drawn line coordinates?

Comment: collision check is maths - you've got to keep the coordinates you use to draw the pixmap line

Comment: i tried storing them into array of circles in my render method. but no working. Can u tell me how can i do that?@dot_Sp0T

Comment: Collisions have NOTHING to do with rendering - collision code is, in theory, completely unrelated to how you render whatever. Have a look at some resources: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26501/how-does-a-collision-engine-work and http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/collision_detection/17005/

Comment: You can use rectangle instead of lines for capturing late collision which you drag directly into rectangle without hitting edges.